# Single-ended or differential for very high frequency?

Tags: single-ended

When reading the  [ADF4371 evb datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/user-guides/EV-ADF4371SD2Z-UG-1474.pdf),
I realized that 16-32 GHz output uses only single-ended but all other outputs use differential output. Doesn't it mean for very high frequency the single-ended is better?
Thanks.

Comment: what does  `better` mean?

Comment: Try not to draw generalizations after seeing a single instance of something, especially when criteria that reduces "betterness" are present, such as cost and ease of implementation. There are also criteria such as usage differences: For example, is the 16-32GHz output intended to be run over a distance that is as long as the other outputs?

Comment: @DKNguyen This is as good an answer as any. I might also add: maybe they didn't have room for all the connectors on that side.

Comment: Single ended is used for RF from the AM radio band (hundreds of KHz) to mm wave (terahertz), and in applications from radio, television, radar, communications, etc.  So NO, nothing frequency-wise dictates differential or single ended.